# What does 'quantization' mean in interpreter.get_input_details()?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite, quantization

Using tflite and getting properties of interpreter like :

```
print(interpreter.get_input_details())

[{'name': 'input_1_1', 'index': 47, 'shape': array([  1, 128, 128,   3], dtype=int32), 'dtype': <class 'numpy.uint8'>, 'quantization': (0.003921568859368563, 0)}]
```

What does `'quantization': (0.003921568859368563, 0)` mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means quantization parameters values: scale and zero_point of input tensor.

This is necessary to convert a quantized uint8 number q to floating point number f using formula:

```
f = (q - zero_point) * scale
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the [documentation of `get_input_details`](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/api_docs/python/tf/lite/Interpreter#get_input_details) doesn't explain:

> ```
> Returns: A list of input details.
> ```

But if you look the source code `get_input_details`, it calls `_get_tensor_details` ([source](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/85c8b2a817f95a3e979ecd1ed95bff1dc1335cff/tensorflow/lite/python/interpreter.py#L314)), and this function does document it:

```py
    """Gets tensor details.
    Args:
      tensor_index: Tensor index of tensor to query.
    Returns:
      A dictionary containing the following fields of the tensor:
        'name': The tensor name.
        'index': The tensor index in the interpreter.
        'shape': The shape of the tensor.
        'quantization': Deprecated, use 'quantization_parameters'. This field
            only works for per-tensor quantization, whereas
            'quantization_parameters' works in all cases.
        'quantization_parameters': The parameters used to quantize the tensor:
          'scales': List of scales (one if per-tensor quantization)
          'zero_points': List of zero_points (one if per-tensor quantization)
          'quantized_dimension': Specifies the dimension of per-axis
              quantization, in the case of multiple scales/zero_points.
```

---

### What does it mean?

These quantization parameters are values used to quantize (convert a range of numbers from one range to another more limited range, e.g. 0-10 into 0-1). In TensorFlow, this is specifically used to mean when the data type changes to a data type which supports fewer numbers: e.g. float32 to float16, or float32 to uint8, or float16 to int8. Dequantization is the reverse (e.g. when you want to get probabilities out of a model which was quantized to uint8 and the quantized output is between 0-255).

The maths is quite simple, like a more general form normalization (making something range from (0 to 1):

- quantization: `q = (f / s) + z`
- dequantization: `f = (q - z) * s`
- For more on this quantization equation, see the [Quantization Specification](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/performance/quantization_spec).

---

**Note:** `Aleksandr Kondratyev`'s equation `f = (q - zero_point) * scale` is actually dequantization, since it takes q (quantized value) and provides you f (float). Of course you can reverse the equation to get the other one.