# Understanding tf.contrib.lite.TFLiteConverter quantization parameters

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorflow-lite, quantization

I'm trying to use UINT8 quantization while converting tensorflow model to tflite model:

If use `post_training_quantize = True`, model size is x4 lower then original fp32 model, so I assume that model weights are uint8, but when I load model and get input type via `interpreter_aligner.get_input_details()[0]['dtype']` it's float32. Outputs of the quantized model are about the same as original model.

```
converter = tf.contrib.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_frozen_graph(
        graph_def_file='tflite-models/tf_model.pb',
        input_arrays=input_node_names,
        output_arrays=output_node_names)
converter.post_training_quantize = True
tflite_model = converter.convert()
```

Input/output of converted model:

```
print(interpreter_aligner.get_input_details())
print(interpreter_aligner.get_output_details())
[{'name': 'input_1_1', 'index': 47, 'shape': array([  1, 128, 128,   3], dtype=int32), 'dtype': <class 'numpy.float32'>, 'quantization': (0.0, 0)}]
[{'name': 'global_average_pooling2d_1_1/Mean', 'index': 45, 'shape': array([  1, 156], dtype=int32), 'dtype': <class 'numpy.float32'>, 'quantization': (0.0, 0)}]
```

Another option is to specify more parameters explicitly:
Model size is x4 lower then original fp32 model, model input type is uint8, but model outputs are more like garbage.

```
converter = tf.contrib.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_frozen_graph(
        graph_def_file='tflite-models/tf_model.pb',
        input_arrays=input_node_names,
        output_arrays=output_node_names)
converter.post_training_quantize = True
converter.inference_type = tf.contrib.lite.constants.QUANTIZED_UINT8
converter.quantized_input_stats = {input_node_names[0]: (0.0, 255.0)}  # (mean, stddev)
converter.default_ranges_stats = (-100, +100)
tflite_model = converter.convert()
```

Input/output of converted model:

```
[{'name': 'input_1_1', 'index': 47, 'shape': array([  1, 128, 128,   3], dtype=int32), 'dtype': <class 'numpy.uint8'>, 'quantization': (0.003921568859368563, 0)}]
[{'name': 'global_average_pooling2d_1_1/Mean', 'index': 45, 'shape': array([  1, 156], dtype=int32), 'dtype': <class 'numpy.uint8'>, 'quantization': (0.7843137383460999, 128)}]
```

So my questions are:

1. What is happenning when only `post_training_quantize = True` is set? i.e. why 1st case work fine, but second don't.
2. How to estimate mean, std and range parameters for second case?
3. Looks like in second case model inference is faster, is it depend on the fact that model input is uint8?
4. What means `'quantization': (0.0, 0)` in 1st case and `'quantization': (0.003921568859368563, 0)`,`'quantization': (0.7843137383460999, 128)` in 2nd case?
5. What is `converter.default_ranges_stats` ?

**Update:**

Answer to question 4 is found [What does 'quantization' mean in interpreter.get_input_details()?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54830126/1179925)

Comment: @suharshs Looks like you related to this part of tensorflow, can you eleborate on this?

Comment: 4a. **quantization** is ignored for **dtype** of **float32**

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> What is happenning when only post_training_quantize = True is set? i.e. why 1st case work fine, but second don't.

In TF 1.14, this seems to just quantize the weights stored on disk, in the .tflite file. This does not, by itself, set the inference mode to quantized inference.

i.e., You can have a tflite model which has inference type `float32` but the model weights are quantized (using `post_training_quantize=True`) for the sake of lower disk size, and faster loading of the model at runtime.

> How to estimate mean, std and range parameters for second case?

The documentation is confusing to many. Let me explain what I concluded after some research :

1. Unfortunately quantization parameters/stats has 3 **equivalent** forms/representations across the TF library and documentation :

   - A) `(mean, std_dev)`
   - B) `(zero_point, scale)`
   - C) `(min,max)`
2. Conversion from B) and A):

   - `std_dev = 1.0 / scale`
   - `mean = zero_point`
3. Conversion from C) to A):

   - `mean = 255.0*min / (min - max)`
   - `std_dev = 255.0 / (max - min)`
   - Explanation: quantization stats are parameters used for mapping the range (0,255) to an arbitrary range, you can start from the 2 equations: `min / std_dev + mean = 0` and `max / std_dev + mean = 255`, then follow the math to reach the above conversion formulas
4. Conversion from A) to C):

   - `min = - mean * std_dev`
   - `max = (255 - mean) * std_dev`
5. The naming "mean" and "std_dev" are confusing and are largely seen as misnomers.

To answer your question: , if your input image has :

- range (0,255) then `mean = 0, std_dev = 1`
- range (-1,1) then `mean = 127.5, std_dev = 127.5`
- range (0,1) then `mean = 0, std_dev = 255`

> Looks like in second case model inference is faster, is it depend on the fact that model input is uint8?

Yes, possibly. However quantized models are typically slower unless you make use of vectorized instructions of your specific hardware. TFLite is optimized to run those specialized instruction for ARM processors. As of TF 1.14 or 1.15 if you are running this on your local machine x86 Intel or AMD, then I'd be surprised if the quantized model runs faster. [Update: It's on TFLite's roadmap to add first-class support for x86 vectorized instructions to make quantized inference faster than float]

> What means 'quantization': (0.0, 0) in 1st case and 'quantization': (0.003921568859368563, 0),'quantization': (0.7843137383460999, 128) in 2nd case?

Here this has the format is `quantization: (scale, zero_point)`

In your first case, you only activated `post_training_quantize=True`, and this doesn't make the model run quantized inference, so there is no need to transform the inputs or the outputs from float to uint8. Thus quantization stats here are essentially `null`, which is represented as `(0,0)`.

In the second case, you activated quantized inference by providing `inference_type = tf.contrib.lite.constants.QUANTIZED_UINT8`. So you have quantization parameters for both input and output, which are needed to transform your float input to uint8 on the way in to the model, and the uint8 output to a float output on the way out.

- At input, do the transformation: `uint8_array = (float_array / std_dev) + mean`
- At output, do the transformation: `float_array = (uint8_array.astype(np.float32) - mean) * std_dev`
- Note .astype(float32) this is necessary in python to get correct calculation
- Note that other texts may use `scale` instead of `std_dev` so the divisions will become multiplications and vice versa.

Another confusing thing here is that, even though during conversion you specify `quantization_stats = (mean, std_dev)`, the `get_output_details` will return `quantization: (scale, zero_point)`, not just the form is different (scale vs std_dev) but also the order is different!

Now to understand these quantization parameter values you got for the input and output, let's use the formulas above to deduce the range of real values (`(min,max)`) of your inputs and outputs. Using the above formulas we get :

- Input range : `min = 0, max=1` (it is you who specified this by providing `quantized_input_stats = {input_node_names[0]: (0.0, 255.0)}  # (mean, stddev)` )
- Output range: `min = -100.39, max=99.6`

Comment: Is `converter.default_ranges_stats` corresponds to `min`, `max` in your answer?

Comment: Also following your equations `if input image range [0,1] then mean = 0, std_dev = 255`, then `min = - mean * std_dev`, `max = (255 - mean) * std_dev` -> min=0, max=255*255, so where is `min = -100.39, max=99.6` come from?

Comment: Yes `default_ranges_stats` specify `(min,max)`

Comment: For your output you have `get_output_details()` returning `'quantization': (0.7843137383460999, 128)`

So `min = -128 * 0.7434313 = -100.39`, `max = (255-128)*0.7434313 = 99.6`.
Let me know if you spot a mistake

Comment: @mrgloom also remember to Accept the best answer

Comment: I still don't get it. Is `default_ranges_stats` influence values that are shown for output layer `'quantization': (0.7843137383460999, 128)`, i.e. does it mean that values `min = -128 * 0.7434313 = -100.39, max = (255-128)*0.7434313 = 99.6` are close to `(-100, +100)`? based on what `default_ranges_stats` should be set? Should I estimate all possible outputs of network on my dataset and set `default_ranges_stats` range based on that?

Comment: Yes, `default_range_stats` influences the quantization params of not just the output, but every tensor in your graph. Note that you should never define `default_range_stats` yourself. This option is available only for debugging. The right way is to quantize-aware-train your model, so that each tensor have it's own min/max based on the training data : https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/r1.13/tensorflow/contrib/quantize

Comment: To be precise, it does not just "influences"...`default_range_stats` IS THE quantization parameters, specified in `(min,max)` format, but then stored in the .tflite file in the `(scale, zero_point)` format, which is what you see in `get_output_details()`

Comment: So with `post_training_quantize = True`(without params) I get model with uint8 weights and inference is in float32, but only way to get model with uint8 weight and uint8 inference is  `quantization-aware training` ? Is there any reason to specify additional params of `converter` when `post_training_quantize = True` is used?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200003/discussion-between-mohamedezz-and-mrgloom).

Answer (score 5):

1) See [documantation](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/performance/post_training_quantization). In short, this technique allows you to get a quantized uint8 graph with an accuracy of work that is close to the original one and does not require further training of the quantized model. However, the speed is noticeably less than if [conventional](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/quantize/README.md) quantization were used.

2) If your model has trained with normalized [-1.0, 1.0] input you should set `converter.quantized_input_stats = {input_node_names[0]: (128, 127)}`, and after that quantization of input tensor will be close to `(0.003921568859368563, 0)`. `mean` is the integer value from 0 to 255 that maps to floating point 0.0f. `std_dev` is 255 / (float_max - float_min). This will fix one possible problem

3) Uint8 neural network inference is about 2 times faster (based on device), then float32 inference

Comment: For `2) ` did you mean image preprocessing? I use bgr image as input divided by 255.0, so my input in range [0,1], so as I understand in my case it will be mean=0.0 and std_dev=255.0 What about `converter.default_ranges_stats` ?

Comment: Yes, it depends on image preprocessing.

About default_ranges_stats. In general to create quantized tflite graph all tensors have to have min/max information of possible values. This information will be used to create quantization parameters: scale and zero_point. If this minmax values are missing, then it will be used minmax from  default_ranges_stats, in this case this mean, that quantized graph inference will be garbage like

Comment: Is there some way to see that a TFLite model did pass `post_training_quantize`? In my test, running **//tensorflow/lite/tools:visualize** on both models gives same results (not identical, buffer indices are different). Also, timecost to run inference for the two models (in CPU) does not statistically change.