# Understanding Tensorflow Object Detection UINT8 Quantization Command

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite, object-detection-api, quantization

I tried to quantize model trained using object detection api and it successfuly worked following google document. To convert frozen graph to quantized UINT8 tflite file, I used command

```
tflite_convert \
  --output_file="${OUTPUT_DIR}/output_tflite_graph.tflite" \
  --graph_def_file="${OUTPUT_DIR}/tflite_graph.pb" \
  --inference_type=QUANTIZED_UINT8 \
  --input_arrays="${INPUT_TENSORS}" \
  --output_arrays="${OUTPUT_TENSORS}" \
  --mean_values=128 \
  --std_dev_values=128 \
  --input_shapes=1,300,300,3 \
  --change_concat_input_ranges=false \
  --allow_nudging_weights_to_use_fast_gemm_kernel=true \
  --allow_custom_ops
```

On quantization, I set std_dev_values to 128, and std_dev_values to 128. According to another question here: [Understanding tf.contrib.lite.TFLiteConverter quantization parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54830869/understanding-tf-contrib-lite-tfliteconverter-quantization-parameters/58096430#58096430)
This range corresponds to input image values range [-1,1]

However, during inference my inference will only work when I use input image value in range [0-255]! I am again confused about what should I set for **std_dev_values** and **mean_values** for other circumstances.

Here is my project and inference code: https://github.com/zye1996/edgetpu_ssd_lpr

I suspect object detection api has preprocess to scale input data but I cannot find references and do not know what causes the conflict. Please help!

Comment: Images have values between 0,255 per channel. Your tflite model does the standardization by itself as you define in the conversion. If you enter an already standardized variable  ([-1, 1], [0,1] or whatever) it does not expect it.

Comment: I found the reason as each model class has a preprocess function remapping input from [0, 255] to [-1, 1] so std_dev and means are 128 respectively